# 5V Pressure sensor module with 3.3V ADC

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, esp32, pressure

I'm using ESP32 to read analogue pressure readings from [this pressure transducer](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1pc-Pressure-Transducer-Sender-Sensor-0-4-5V-Steel-for-Oil-Fuel-100-200-300psi/382174689867?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=651027875038&_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649). My Problem is this sensor outputs 0.5V – 4.5V linear voltage output based on the pressure but ESP32 can only handle 0 - 3.3V in the ADC inputs. Can anyone advice me to how to accomplish this in 0 - 3.3V range?

[image]

Comment: [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) is what you need ... approx values for R1 and R2 are R2 = 2 * R1 ... that will produce 3v on 4.5v input

Comment: @JaromandaX That could work if the output is low impedance. It may not be though, in which case it would need to be buffered first, since the voltage divider would mess things up royally.

Comment: LOL... Gotta love Chinese specifications... `Insulation Resistance: >100mΩ 500VDC`... *milli* ohms?!?!

Comment: @Majenko you can't challenge that statement.. In fact it should be greater than 100 milliohms... Hopefully ;)

Comment: @frarugi87 You right that it's not "wrong" ;) It's just like saying that "The temperature today is greater than 3 Kelvin"...

Comment: @JaromandaX, Thanks for the comment and thats what exactly i wanted. I can accept it as the correct answer if you could just put it as an answer.